# Facebook query to ad group conversions returning a different result when running on a different machine

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

We have a query that returns a different response when running on an EC2 instance than it does on a local dev machine.

The queries are identical:

```
[AD_ACT_NUMBER]/adgroupconversions/?appsecret_proof=[APP_SECRET_PROOF]&include_deleted=false&start_time=1393372800&end_time=1393459200&aggregate_days=1&limit=500
```

On the local dev machine this query returns a response including:

```
[{"adgroup_id"=>[SPECIFIC AD GROUP],
 "values"=>
 [{"start_time"=>1393372800,
   "end_time"=>1393459200,
   "conversions"=>
    [{"action_type"=>"[CONVERSION I CARE ABOUT]",
      "object_id"=>"[OBJECT ID]",
      "post_click_1d"=>5,
      "post_click_7d"=>7,
      "post_click_28d"=>7},
     ...etc
```

However on the ec2 instance, the same code, producing the same query, returns a slightly different result.

```
[{"adgroup_id"=>[SPECIFIC AD GROUP],
 "values"=>
 [{"start_time"=>1393372800,
   "end_time"=>1393459200,
   "conversions"=>
    [{"action_type"=>"[CONVERSION I CARE ABOUT]",
      "object_id"=>"[OBJECT ID]",
      "post_click_1d"=>5,
      "post_click_7d"=>6,
      "post_click_28d"=>6},
     ...etc
```

The conversions are, for some reason, 1 less. The one with 7 appears to be correct and matches
the result when the query is pasted into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and the result when looking at the reports in facebook ads manager.

We're using ruby and koala to make the queries. Koala is using Faraday and having pry-ed into the code at run time I've been able to confirm that when it makes the raw http query to Facebook the queries are indeed the same. Both queries are using the same access token and the same appsecret_proof.

At first we thought it might be a timezone issue but seeing as both requests have identical start and end times we're not sure how. Also, while the ec2 instance is in UTC and the dev box in GMT, both UTC and GMT are currently the same time. Then we checked to see if Koala or Faraday had built in cacheing but found nothing, and changing the query to include_deleted=true to break any sort of cache made no difference.

The only other thought we had was that the facebook api has some cacheing based on request IP,
however this seems distinctly unlikely.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Cheers

Max

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of your evidence, the only conclusion that I can really come to is that perhaps the cloud instance is talking to a different Facebook server and one server is slightly out of sync with the one the dev machine happens to be hitting?

I can honestly say I've seen some strange things as well.  I have some ads code that has, as of this moment 230 unit tests (some are really integration tests) and they make various calls to Facebook Ads end points...  At times I've seen results between test executions vary from say, reach estimate end point by an order of magnitude different.  Of course some variation is expected, but not a difference as vast as going from something like 0.79 to 12.89.  All I can ever really conclude is that Facebook has to have a massive number of servers and it's completely logical to expect to wind up hitting a different one if they have any sort of load balancing in place and perhaps one server is slightly out of sync, etc..

Only concern is, which one is the truth at that point?

Sorry I don't really have a better answer than that, if the queries and the code base are indeed identical, I don't see any other real logical answer to explain why the variation.  I guess this response really does nothing to solve the problem and probably should really be a comment, but the question is, what is the "right" answer in this case?  Maybe a Facebook person can better speak to this topic?

Comment: Cheers man, the server idea is an interesting one, hadn't considered that. Trying to get hold of a Facebook person at the moment, if they get back I'll put their answer up here.